# Need equivalent AIX script for Linux script - specifically the find command

Tags: shell, find, aix

Under Linux the following line creates a text file:

```
find "/path/to/pdfs/" -type f -name "$1*.pdf" -printf "%TY/%Tm/%Td %TH:%TM %p\n" \
    | sort -n -k1.1,1.2 -k1.3,1.4 -k1.6,1.7 -k1.9,1.10 -k2.1,2.2 -k2.4,2.5 -k3 \
    > remoteuser@remoteserver:/u/tmp/CustTmp/zzz_pdfs.txt
```

This text file contains this:

```
2013/12/31 16:43 /path/to/pdfs/list1.pdf
2013/12/31 17:36 /path/to/pdfs/list2.pdf
2013/12/31 17:38 /path/to/pdfs/list3.pdf
```

Under AIX the above command fails because `-printf` doesn't exist in the `find` command on AIX. How to work around this limitation?

Comment: This is related to `find`, not to `bash` or `ksh`. Are you running these on different systems? What does `find --version` say on each of them?

Comment: yes two different systems/OS's (Linux VS AIX) On Linux the find version is 4.4.2; on AIX the "find --version" command returns a "Usage: ..." result

Comment: In future, best to tag you AIX problems with AIX, as it is very different from the Linux that most people are familiar with. You might see if your SysAdmins are aware of any alternate versions of find. It is possible to install the GNU find on AIX, but not a common practice. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having isn't a shell issue. It's that your `find` commands aren't compatible.

I am guessing that you are running Bash on a Linux box, and Kornshell on Solaris. The problem is that your Linux box has the GNU version of the `find` command which has things like the `-printf` parameter while the `find` command on your other system does not because it's using the BSD or AT&T Unix version of the command.

What you need to do is to use your system's `stat` command to pull the information you want from the file:

```
find "/path/to/pdfs/" -type f -name "$1*.pdf" -exec stat ??? {}\; | sort ...
```

The problem is I don't know the format of the stat command. Unfortunately, this command varies from system to system. It looks like you're creating a sorting modification date according to the GNU documentation on the [find time directives](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Format-Directives). Here's an equivalent on my Mac running Mavericks:

```
find "/path/to/pdfs/" -type f -name "$1*.pdf" -exec stat -f "%10Dm %SN" {}\; | sort ...
```

The `-f` parameter specifies a format on how stat will print its information. The "%10Dm`specifies 10 decimal digits (`D`) of the modification time`m`. The`%SN` specifies the file's name in string format. This prints the date as the number of seconds from the Epoch (usually Jan 1, 1970).

In your original sort, you were specify each and every field of the date time stamp (which wasn't really necessary, so your `sort` will be simpler:

```
find "/path/to/pdfs/" -type f -name "$1*.pdf" -exec stat -f "%10Dm %SN" {}\; \
    | sort -k1,1n -k2,2
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't print out the time in a nice neat format like you want. So, we'll strip off the file name after the sort and pass that through `stat` again printing the file

```
find "/path/to/pdfs/" -type f -name "$1*.pdf" -exec stat -f "%10Dm %SN" {}\; \
    | sort -k1,1n -k2,2  sed 's/.* //'
    | while read file
    do
        stat "%-22.22Sm %N" $file
    done
```

This will print out your files as:

```
Dec 12 15:38:43 2013   /path/to/pdfs/list1.pdf
```

Not exactly the same, but it's close. Actually, on my Mac, I can take the numeric output of the date from the first stat command, and convert it into the date string in the exact format you want.

Unfortunately, this particular feature of the date command has the same problem as the `-printf` parameter in the `find`: It's machine specific, so it doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Thanks David, I will give this a go and report back!

Comment: Well this wouldn't work either on AIX - Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

The printf command does exist the printf specifiers are different, try:

```
printf "%(%Y/%m/%d %H:%M)T\n"
```

Comment: The "-printf" option of the find command does NOT exist under ksh. I know the printf command exists under KSH. Hence my question.

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with ksh. It's about the version of the `find` command that exists on AIX. `man find` should tell you what options are available. (If you need GNU-specific options, you may be able to install GNU `findutils`, either as a binary package or by building from source.)